# AdomdDataReader GetValue(0) returning ???? instead of non-english characters

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-analysis-services

My goal is to grab all the unique values from certain columns in certain tables in an Azure Analysis Service via a C# Azure function app.

My code works fine however the GetValue from the AdomdDataReader returns '?' strings instead of chinese characters. For English strings it works fine. How do I handle retrievng non-english strings with the AdomdDataReader? I see no other way to retrieve values from the docs.

Thanks.

Code below:

```
AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection($"Data Source={server};User ID=app:{appId};Password={authKey};Catalog={dataBase}");

        List<ColumnData> cols = CreateData();

        List<List<Object>> lists = new List<List<Object>>();

        foreach (var col in cols)
        
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"tableName: {col.tableName}, columnMame: {col.columnName}");
            // string txt = "SELECT DISTINCT({[Timeframes].[Timeframe].[Timeframe]}) on columns, DISTINCT({[DimRetailer].[Consumer Global Parent].[Consumer Global Parent]}) on rows from [Model]";
            string txt1 = "SELECT DISTINCT({[DimOSVersion].[OS Version].[OS Version]}) on columns, ";
            string txt2 = "DISTINCT({[" + col.tableName + "].[" + col.columnName + "]" + ".[" + col.columnName + "]}) on rows from [Model]";
            string txt = txt1 + txt2;
            conn.Open();
            AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand(txt, conn);
            AdomdDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
            lists.Add(list);

            // output the rows in the DataReader
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                var value = dr.GetValue(0);
                if(value != null)
                    if (value.ToString() !=  null)
                        list.Add(value);
                
            }

            dr.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You are **100% sure** the data is fine in the data source? i.e. is it possible the _source_ of the data has the `?` in it?

Comment: Simple console app also return '????' on your side, isn't it? I think the problem comes from your machine system. You can have a look of my answer.

Comment: Hi, any update? Do you see the answer I post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem. I am also get '????' on my side when the data is Chinese language.

[image]

I am not sure the OS on your side, if your OS in win10, then the steps are below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem comes from your system location of your machine. Above is the way to solve it

After that code can work fine instead of return '????':

[image]

And after deploy your function app, it should also works. It should be the problem of your machine.